# How to set types for mounting function in enzyme tests?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I'm using Typescript and Enzyme for testing react components. I'm very new to Typescript.

I've got this helper function in tests:

```
const getComponent = (mountFn = shallow) => (
  mountFn(<Component />)
)
```

This works when I run it as `getComponent()` but as soon I do `getComponent(mount)` it fails because typescript assumes `getComponent` returns ShallowWrapper.

I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I tell Typescript that `mountFn` can be either `shallow` or `mount`?
2. How do I tell it that the return value can be of type `ShallowWrapper` or `ReactWrapper`?
3. Ideally - how do I tell it that the return value should be of type `ShallowWrapper` when `shallow` was passed and `ReactWrapper` when `mount` was passed?
4. How do I do this using typings that are already defined in @types/enzyme?
5. Is this a good practice at all? I used to do it all the time before using typescript but maybe I should just create 2 separate functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I tell Typescript that `mountFn` can be either shallow or mount?

This will do the trick.

```
import {ShallowWrapper, ReactWrapper} from 'enzyme';

type mountFnType<P, S> = (node: React.ReactElement<P>, options?: any): ShallowWrapper<P, S> | ReactWrapper<P, S>

const getComponent = <P, S>(mountFn: mountFnType<P, S>) => (
     mountFn(<Component />)
)
```

Here if you wish you can create a type alias for `ShallowWrapper` and `ReactWrapper`using the [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

```
type Wrapper<P, S> =  ShallowWrapper<P, S> | ReactWrapper<P, S>;
```

Now, your function will look like,

```
type mountFnType<P, S> = (node: React.ReactElement<P>, options?: any) => Wrapper<P, S>;

const getComponent = <P, S>(mountFn: mountFnType<P, S>) => (
     mountFn(<Component />)
)
```

> How do I tell it that the return value can be of type ShallowWrapper or ReactWrapper?

By adding the return type,

```
const getComponent = <P, S>(mountFn: mountFnType<P, S>): Wrapper<P, S>
```

> Ideally - how do I tell it that the return value should be of type ShallowWrapper when shallow was passed and ReactWrapper when mount was passed?

You don't need to specify it manually.

> How do I do this using typings that are already defined in @types/enzyme?

We are already using type definition of `shallow` and `mount` from `@types/enzyme`.

> Is this a good practice at all? I used to do it all the time before using typescript but maybe I should just create 2 separate functions?

It's just a matter of preference, I guess. You can use the helper functions to make some work easier. If I were at your place, I would have also passed the component as the 2nd argument. So finally your code will look like,

```
import {ShallowWrapper, ReactWrapper} from 'enzyme';

type Wrapper<P, S> =  ShallowWrapper<P, S> | ReactWrapper<P, S>;

type mountFnType<P, S> = (node: React.ReactElement<P>, options?: any) => Wrapper<P, S>;

const getComponent = <P, S>(mountFn: mountFnType<P, S>, CustomComponent: React.ComponentClass<P>): Wrapper<P, S> => {
      return mountFn(<CustomComponent />);
};
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!

However I got two errors:

`type Wrapper<P, S> = ShallowWrapper<P, S> | ReactWrapper<P, S>;` 

This gives me "Cannot find name ShallowWrapper" (and ReactWrapper as well) - this was the reason I was asking how do I use @types/enzyme 

`mountFn = shallow | mount` - this guy gives me "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

Comment: Ok I guess in order to get rid of the first error I need to import Wrappers from enzyme: `import { shallow, mount, ShallowWrapper, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";`

For the second error I tried: `mountFn: typeof mount | typeof shallow = shallow`

it looks like it's working but now I have an error inside `mountFn` function:
`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Thanks for your help I will keep investigating

Comment: I've updated the answer completely. Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: sorry, your final solution does not work for me, this line give me errors:
`type mountFnType<P, S> = (node: React.ReactElement<P>, options?: any): Wrapper<P, S>;`
1. colon is not expected (rather `=>`) 2. `Wrapper is used as a value and it referes to a type etc.

Comment: I guess this works if you change colon for fat arrow - after all mountFnType should describe function. Please edit the answer and I will accept. Thanks a lot for your help!